# Transfer a value from ViewModel to another ViewModel (JavaFX, mvvm, afterburner.fx)

Tags: java, javafx, mvvm

I want to create an app with JavaFX and I have a problem with separated views (splited by afterburner.fx) and the mvvm principal.
In my scenario i have one view with a textfield and a button and a second view with a listview.
Now I write some text in the textfield to add the text to the list by clicking the button.
I have four classes (view and viewmodel for textfield/button and list).
Now the question: How can I react to the buttonclick and transfer the text from the textfield to the list?

I can bind the text in the view and a property in the viewModel. But how can I transfer the value to the viewmodel of the list?

I hope somebody can help me with this understanding problem.

Big Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea here is to use a single data model, which is shared among the components that need to access shared data. Using `@Inject` in afterburner.fx will provide a convenient way to manage this for you.

For design patterns, the first thing to note is that afterburner.fx (and to a lesser extent, perhaps, the FXML-"controller" mechanism in general) is really based on a MVP pattern (not a MVVM pattern). The FXML file represents the (passive) view; the presenter is of course the presenter, and the model is implemented according to the application requirements.

Typically, the framework you are using is a big part of the decision about which pattern(s) to use, so I think my main recommendation would be to use a MVP pattern here. Using MVP, this looks like the following:

You can create an `ObservableList` in your model:

```
public class Model {

    private final ObservableList<String> itemList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<String> getItemList() {
        return itemList ;
    }

}
```

Then in the presenter for the view that has the `ListView`, do:

```
public class ListPresenter {

    @Inject
    private Model model ;

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView ;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        listView.setItems(model.getItemList());
    }
}
```

so that the `ListView` uses the `ObservableList` in the model for its backing list of items. This means that if that list changes, then the `ListView` will automatically update.

In the presenter for the view that has the text field, you do:

```
public class AddItemPresenter {

    @Inject
    private Model model ;

    @FXML
    private TextField textField ;

    // handler for button press:
    @FXML
    private void handleButton() {
        model.getItemList().add(textField.getText());
    }
}
```

Now when the button is pressed, the text in the text field is added to the model's item list. Because you set that list as the backing list for the list view, the text appears in the list view.

---

If you want to force a MVVM pattern here, I think you have to consider the "View" in MVVM as comprising the FXML-presenter pair from afterburner. So you end up with something that looks like a M(VP)VM pattern. I am not as familiar with MVVM as I am with MVC and MVP, but as I understand it there are three components: the familiar data model (M), the view (V), and the view model (VM). The role of the view model is to represent the state of the view, including actions, but it knows nothing about the actual view itself. In the example above, you would have two view models; one for each of the views. Note that a data model (M) still exists, and of course the view models will need access to it. They need to share the same data model instance, so they can access and manipulate the same data.

I think an implementation of this looks like

```
public class ListViewModel {

    @Inject
    private Model model ;

    private final StringProperty selectedItem = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public ObservableList<String> getItems() {
        return model.getItemList();
    }

    public StringProperty selectedItemProperty() {
        return selectedItem ;
    }

    public String getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItemProperty().get();
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(String item) {
        selectedItemProperty().set(item);
    }
}
```

The `Model` class is the same as before. The job of the presenter (view in MVVM) is to bind the view to the view model:

```
public class ListViewPresenter {

    @Inject
    private ListViewModel viewModel ;

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView ;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        listView.setItems(viewModel.getItems());
        viewModel.selectedItemProperty().bind(listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
    }
}
```

Similarly the view model for the "add item" module looks like

```
public class AddItemViewModel {

    @Inject 
    private Model model ;

    private final StringProperty currentItem = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private final Runnable addItemAction = this::addItem ;

    public StringProperty currentItemProperty() {
        return currentItem ;
    }

    public String getCurrentItem() {
        return currentItemProperty().get();
    }

    public void setCurrentItem(String item) {
        currentItemProperty().set(item);
    }

    public Runnable getAddItemAction() {
        return addItemAction ;
    }

    private void addItem() {
        model.getItemList().add(getCurrentItem());
        setCurrentItem("");
    }
}
```

and the `AddItemPresenter` now looks like

```
public class AddItemPresenter {

    @Inject
    private AddItemViewModel viewModel ;

    @FXML
    private TextField textField ;

    @FXML
    private Button addButton ;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        viewModel.currentItemProperty().bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty());
        addButton.setOnAction(e -> viewModel.getAddItemAction().run());
    }
}
```

The effect here is really just to insert an additional layer between the view and the (data) model. The net effect feels as though the presenter now doesn't really "pull its weight", which is usually an indication that the application is over-engineered and has too many layers. However, you do gain an advantage in that the view model is now much more "test-friendly" than the presenter (and can be made more so by providing a setter or constructor parameter for the injected model, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I interpret the presenters as the views in the Model-View-ViewModel principle. So they don't have any view logic.
They only connect the view elements like the ListView with the ViewModel.
In the example the Presenter have logic 

listView.setItems(model.getItemList());
model.getItemList().add(textField.getText());

and that isn't really test friendly (because @Inject and @FXML).
In my opinion, the viewmodels have to handle that communication.
Is that a wrong deliberation?

THX

Comment: @user2558928 The underlying pattern used by afterburner.fx is a MVP (passive view) pattern (this is pretty much true if you use FXML and "controller" classes too). Forcing a MVVM design on top of this is going to be tricky - you would end up with some sort of M(VP)VM design. Perhaps you could add some code to your question to show what you are starting from?

Comment: @user2558928 See update with a MVVM approach (I think...).

Comment: thx, thats was the answer. I totally forgot the model layer -.-